# How should I prevent a .pic definition inside a document environment, but outside a tikzpicture, from adding a space to the typeset output?

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, tikz-styles, best-practices, tikz-pic

How can I prevent the definition of a `.pic` from adding an additional space to the typeset output, where the `.pic` is defined in a `\tikzset{}` within the document body, rather than either in the preamble or within a `tikzpicture` environment?

Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{make me/.pic={\node{#1};}}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node {a};
  \draw (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: unwanted space]

A slightly-less-M WE shows that the additional space is added with a standard class also.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{tikz}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}
x%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node {a};
  \draw (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}

x\tikzset{make me/.pic={\node{#1};}}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node {a};
  \draw (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: unwanted space in standard class]

I want that the `\tikzset{}` line makes no difference to the typeset output whatsoever. As far as I'm concerned, it is just defining something. It should only affect the output if that something actually gets used. Otherwise, it should just marginally increase the compilation time.

Note that I know this can be avoided by defining the `.pic` in the preamble or inside the `tikzpicture` environment. I specifically need to prevent it when the `.pic` is defined in the `document` but outside a `tikzpicture`.  The remainder of this post just briefly explains *why* I want to do it this way.

I not uncommonly want to say something like

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
\input{img-group-common}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  ...
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I cannot put the `\input` in the preamble because the picture will be included using the `standalone` package, thus everything in the preamble will be ignored.

I do not want to include the `\input` in the preamble of my main document, because I want to keep the settings in `img-group-common` local to a group of closely related images. Usually, these are pictures with a common structure or which require common elements.

Typically, all `img-group.common.tex` does is `\tikzset{...}`. The problem is, that if `\tikzset{...}` defines a `pic`, a space is added to the typeset output before the `tikzpicture` is typeset.

Comment: I wanted to ask 'What is the best way ...' but the system told me that was too subjective and would be closed. Then I tried 'What is the correct way ...' but it said that was too long. So the 'How should I ...' is SE-speak for 'what is the best way ...?'

Comment: Can this be reproduced using `\documentclass{article}`?

Comment: @Symbol1 Yes, but you need a letter or something before i.e. if the `\tikzset` and `tikzpicture` are right after the `document` begins, the space vanishes. But if you insert an `x` first, you can see the space. Hang on, I'll add that as a second slightly-less-MWE.

Comment: @Symbol1 Please see additional example above. It is also not `\tikzset` itself. I went through a file of settings for a group of pictures and most of the definitions did nothing. The `.pic` was obviously (in light of Sod's Law) right at the end, last but one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is how `.pic` is defined in `tikz.code.tex` line 4636-4640

> ```
> \pgfkeysdef{/handlers/.pic}{%
>   \edef\pgf@temp{\pgfkeyscurrentpath}%
>   \edef\pgf@temp{\expandafter\tikz@smuggle@pics@in\pgf@temp\pgf@stop}%
>   \expandafter\pgfkeys\expandafter{\pgf@temp/.style={code={#1}}}
> }
> ```

The author missed a `%` at the end of line 4639.

---

I reported it as a bug here: https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/426/.

Comment: Nice space-hunting. So would it be best to redefine it myself or should I workaround it some other way? Right now, I'm putting `\unskip` before `\endinput` for the inputted file, but will be a pain to remember to do this - these spaces are troublesome to track down. (At least, for me, they are.)

Comment: I will simply copy this piece of code and paste it after `\usepackage{tikz}` with `%` added. (Do not forget `\makeatletter`; I usually do.)

Comment: If you really want backward-compatibility, I will suggest `\pgfkeysdef{/handlers/.pic fix}{ basically the same thing }`. But honestly I had never cared about it.

Comment: Could one of you report this to get it fixed at source?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That's very optimistic. The `pic` code has so many bugs in it, is could occupy a considerable team of naturalists for some centuries. I'm not quite sure why as this doesn't seem true of PGF/Ti*k*Z generally.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I did it. Why is sourceforge showing my real name??? Maybe I should have not given the real name at the very first place :(

Comment: @Symbol1 Thanks. Does it show it only to you, maybe? By the way, I think you have made a mistake with either the line number range or the specific line number, as they aren't compatible.

Comment: **4**639... stupid laptop keyboard.

Comment: Could you add a link to the bug report?

Answer (score 1):

In case it is useful to anybody, here's a supplement to [Symbol 1's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/368531/), `tex/latex/tikz-pic-fix/tikz-pic-fix.sty`:

```
\ProvidesPackage{tikz-pic-fix}[fix pic handler to eliminate spurious space]
\RequirePackage{tikz}
% ateb Symbol 1: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/368531/
\pgfkeysdef{/handlers/.pic}{% tikz.code.tex: llinellau 4636-4640
  \edef\pgf@temp{\pgfkeyscurrentpath}%
  \edef\pgf@temp{\expandafter\tikz@smuggle@pics@in\pgf@temp\pgf@stop}%
  \expandafter\pgfkeys\expandafter{\pgf@temp/.style={code={#1}}}% collir % yn y côd gwreiddiol
}

\endinput
```

The advantage of this is that you can easily remove the patching code or change it if necessary and then any documents which use `tikz-pic-fix` will just load the standard `tikz` and you don't have to hunt through them to change every application of the fix.

## EDIT

Or a Ti*k*Z library, if you've forgotten what you did with the code ....

```
\ProvidesFile{tikzlibrarypicfix.code.tex}
\pgfkeysdef{/handlers/.pic}{% ateb Symbol 1: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/368531/
  \edef\pgf@temp{\pgfkeyscurrentpath}%
  \edef\pgf@temp{\expandafter\tikz@smuggle@pics@in\pgf@temp\pgf@stop}%
  \expandafter\pgfkeys\expandafter{\pgf@temp/.style={code={#1}}}%
}
\endinput
```